Angular - how to check if ngForm is valid while using custom components
I've created a custom component InputTextComponent:
    @Component({
        selector: "app-input-text",
        templateUrl: "./input-text.component.html",
        styleUrl: "./input-text.component.scss",
        standalone: true,
        imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
    })
    export class InputTextComponent {
        @Input() item: string | undefined;
        @Input() id: string | undefined;
        @Output() itemChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

        onInputChange(value: string) {
            this.item = value;
            this.itemChange.emit(value);
        } 
    }

The input-text.component.html template looks like:
<input
    [id]="id"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="item"
    (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)"
    required
/>


Parent component TestFormComponent using the custom component:
export class TestFormComponent {
...
    @ViewChild("f", { static: true }) ngForm: NgForm | undefined;
...
    onSubmit() {
        console.log("valid", this.ngForm.valid);
    }
...
}

TestForm template:
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
    <app-input-text [(item)]="name" id="test_name"></app-input-text>
</form>


Question:
the form is always valid. If I put the content of the custom component directly into the parent component everything is working well, and the form is invalid up until I enter something into the text field. How can I change that, so I can use my custom component and still have the form validation in place
I've tried to find an answer online but without result so far.

You need to use the ControlValueAccessor, this will take care of all the bindings, all you need to do is use the component as a normal input element, since the below steps will convert it to a supported form element!
Notice how required is added to the component instead of the inner input, if we add it on the component it will get propagated to the inner input!
FULL CODE:
INPUT TEXT:
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
  forwardRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-text',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
  <input
    [id]="id"
    [name]="name"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
  />
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputTextComponent {
  @Input() id!: string;
  @Input() name!: string;
  //The internal data model
  private innerValue: any = '';

  //Placeholders for the callbacks which are later providesd
  //by the Control Value Accessor
  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => {};
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = () => {};

  //get accessor
  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  //set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
      this.onChangeCallback(v);
    }
  }

  //Set touched on blur
  onBlur() {
    this.onTouchedCallback();
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = value;
    }
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }
}

MAIN
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { InputTextComponent } from './app/input-text/input-text.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, InputTextComponent, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
        <app-input-text [(ngModel)]="name" id="test_name" name="test_name" required></app-input-text>
    </form>

    {{f.invalid | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = '';
  @ViewChild('f', { static: true }) ngForm!: NgForm | undefined;

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('valid', this.ngForm!.valid);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

great answer i wanted to know if it is possible the usage   @Input() item: string | undefined;
@Output() itemChange = new EventEmitter();  enable the double binding in

@salhimustapha it will work, but the form functionality will not,so its better to use the ControlValueAccessor,

great answer, I really appreciate. I was playing with the ControlValueAccessor as well, but obviously missed something.
An additional question is, how can I generate inside the "app-input-text" component the id and the name based on the attribute name(!) provided in [(ngModel)]?
Something like:
[(ngModel)]="person.address"
would generate
id = "person_address"
and
name="address"

@DaluaLama We need to provide it manually in a separate input id="person_address"
